# Passing a 2d array of structs in C++

Tags: c++, struct, multidimensional-array, shuffle

I am trying to shuffle a 2D array of structs without using vectors. The code I have so far works in one dimension, but I am having trouble extending it to two dimensions. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

struct bingo {
    int set1;
    int set2;
};

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void randomize(int arr[], int n) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = n-1; i > 0; i--) {
        int j = rand() % (i + 1);
        swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
    }
}

int main() {
    const int n = 28;
    bingo arr[n] = { // array of structs
        {0,1}, {1,2}, {2,3}, {3,4}
    };

    randomize(arr, n); // My error happens here and it says "cannot convert
                       // "bingo* to int* for argument '1' to void randomize(int*, int)

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cout << arr[i].set1 << arr[i].set2 << endl;
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Well, yeah. `randomize()` takes an `int *` and not a `bingo`. You need to change that function to take a `bingo *`, first of all.

Comment: Is this C or C++? You say C but tagged C++. Please either make it valid C or remove mentions of C.

Comment: @Vality From include statements and usage of `std::cout` it's clearly c++. The OP seems to have misconcepstions about the actual language used.

Comment: You can use `std:swap` instead of writing it yourself

Comment: Use `std::vector` and `std::random_shuffle`

Comment: @NeilKirk `std::random_shuffle` is deprecated now, `std::shuffle` should be used

Answer (score 0):

You have type errors in your code. Right now, your code will work in "1d" because all your functions accepts only `ints`, which are "1d". But now with your "2d" version you need to change many of your types to `bingo`. Make these changes,

Line 12: `void swap(int *a, int *b) {` to `void swap(bingo *a, bingo *b) {`

Line 13: `int temp = *a;` to `bingo temp = *a;`

Line 18: `void randomize(int arr[], int n) {` to `void randomize(bingo arr[], int n) {`

The error you got was actually very informative on what was wrong so pay attention to those!